# CollectionViewSource doesn't sort after selecting new tab on TabControl

Tags: wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol, collectionviewsource

I am sorting a datagrid within a UserControl that is displayed inside of a TabControl.

The main window contains the TabControl as shown here.

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="EquipTabs" ItemsSource="{Binding Equipment}" >
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ctrls:MachData DataContext="{Binding Path=MachineViewModel}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The user control sorts the datagrid correctly when the first tab is activated.  However, when I click on a different tab or switch back to the original one, the datagrid doesn't sort.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="StatesSource" Source="{Binding States}" >
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="StartTime" Direction="Descending" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgStates" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatesSource}}">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The trace for the binding shows the following:

```
    Deactivate
    Replace item at level 0 with {NullDataItem}
    Activate with root item MachDataViewModel (hash=25379957)
    At level 0 using cached accessor for MachDataViewModel.States: RuntimePropertyInfo(States)
```

Why does the sort only occur initially?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the way `DataGrid` works. `DataGrid` clears `SortDescriptions` before setting `ItemsSource`.

If we can apply our `SortDescriptions` after `DataGrid` is finished with `ItemsSource`, our `SortDescriptions` will work.

`TargetUpdated` event comes to rescue, but to use it we have to set `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` in our `Binding`.

```
<DataGrid 
   TargetUpdated="dgStates_TargetUpdated"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource StatesSource}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
```

Code :

```
private void dgStates_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionViewSource sc = this.Resources["StatesSource"] as CollectionViewSource;
    sc.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Name", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```